# Is there a way to use variables to instantiate classes with optional arguments in parameter list?

Tags: typescript

I'm hoping to optionally instantiate various classes depending on the value of a variable.

As this Stackblitz shows, https://angular-nsdbu3.stackblitz.io, if there are no parameters in the constructor it works fine, but with parameters in the constructor it fails.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there just no way to do what I'm aiming for if there are parameters in the constructor?

```
// WITH PARAMETERS

export class Foo {
prop1: string;

  constructor(prop1: string="foo!") {
    console.log("Foo constructor: "+prop1);
  }
}

// WITHOUT PARAMETERS

export class Bar {
prop1: string;

   constructor() {
     this.prop1 = "bar!";
     console.log("Bar constructor:"+this.prop1)
   }

}
```

Test Bed:

```
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  objClasses = {
    foo: Foo,
    bar: Bar
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    let thisTypeOne = this.objClasses.foo;
    let myFooObj = new (thisTypeOne)();
    let anotherFooObj = new (thisTypeOne)("bazz"); 
    console.log("My Foo Obj: " + myFooObj.prop1);           // *** Undefined
    console.log("Another Foo Obj: " + anotherFooObj.prop1); // *** Undefined

    let thisTypeTwo = this.objClasses["bar"];
    let myBarObj = new (thisTypeTwo)();
    console.log("My Bar Obj: "+myBarObj.prop1);             // *** bar!
```

Comment: It seems that this code has lost `prop1` property of your classes - `Bar` constructor sets it, but it is not defined. Please complete the example so we can help you.

Comment: As an aside, there should be no need to define it, as the code should still run without an explicit declaration, but I added the declarations any way in the Stackblitz <https://angular-nsdbu3.stackblitz.io>. Still the same result. Also, please feel free to fork the Stackblitz and make any changes you think appropriate, Many thanks in advance for your feedback, and for helping me understand this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Object.create(proto, [propertiesObject])`, pass the class name to this function and it will return the object. But the properties part should be defined as an object, so you can't pass the parameters to the constructor directly. So in your code try this;

`let anotherFooObj = Object.create(thisTypeOne, {prop1:{value:"buzz"}});`

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to set the instance property in the constructor - TypeScript does not do it automatically.

```
export class Foo {
  prop1: string;

  constructor(prop1: string="foo!") {
    console.log("Foo constructor: "+prop1);
    this.prop1 = prop1;
  }
}
```